# By whom is the Trump "Immunity case" presently stayed

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, procedure

According to a number of YouTube videos, when a case is appealed to the Supreme Court, the Court may initially decide on two separate issues:

1. Whether it will grant or deny certiorari.  If *four* or more judges vote in favor *of granting cert*, cert will be granted.  Otherwise, cert will be denied.
2. Whether to stay the earlier court's judgment.  If *five* or more judges vote in favor *of granting a stay* until final judgment, the earlier court's judgment will be stayed.  Otherwise it will not.

A decision to hear a case does not imply any judgment as to whether the appeal has any merit; sometimes the Court may hear a case for the purpose of granting its "stamp of approval" on the lower court's judgment.  On the other hand, judges are only supposed to vote in favor of a stay if a variety of conditions are met, including a belief that the appeal is likely to succeed on the merits.

The Supreme Court's [order](https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/courtorders/022824zr3_febh.pdf) granting cert, however, contains the following:

> Without expressing a view on the merits, this Court directs the Court of Appeals to continue withholding issuance of the mandate until the sending down of the judgment of this Court.  The application for a stay is dismissed as moot.

By what authority is that direction issued?  According to the videos I've seen, issuance of a stay is supposed to require--among other things--a finding that an appeal would likely succeed on the merits, a finding that the Court has *expressly stated* that it has not made.  Is the Court simply indicating that its decision should not be viewed as fulfilling the conditions upon which the lower court's stay would naturally vacate itself, but leaving open the possibility of the lower court's stay being vacated via other means, such as an explicit motion?

Comment: This is a legal question not a political question.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the rest of the Q? I.e. what's your real Q?

Comment: I see you're quoting from the Trump case cert. I'll link that in.

Comment: @JoeW: it's technically on-topic here too, but give that it's asking about the intricacies of court procedure, it would get a faster answer on Law SE.

Comment: I'll still add though that "by whom" seems an odd question. Because "The application for a stay is dismissed as moot."

Comment: I don't grok what "continue withholding issuance of the mandate" means in the court's verbiage. What mandate are they talking about would be a better Q, imho. I guess it's the arrest mandate for Trump? In that case what they seem to be ... staying his arrest while not staying any other parts of the lower court's decision. (But I'm not sure what those might) Do note that they only took the case on a narrow issue, specified in the cert, not a whole-case review.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat if the lower court has stayed its own ruling, then the answer is "the lower court" and the supreme court's dismissal is not puzzling.  If the lower court's "withholding" the judgment is not technically a stay, the dismissal is perhaps slightly more puzzling, but only as far as understanding the technical operation of the court system.  Some questions that could be asked on [Law.SE] are also on topic here because they have political implications.  This doesn't seem to be among them.  I would vote to migrate to Law.SE if that were an option.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat a document authorizing an arrest is a "warrant," not a "mandate."  There's no cause to arrest Trump at this point; the trial is pending.  The "narrow issue" here is whether the trial can continue.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat This question seems to be asking legal questions about how a court can do something which isn't a political question but a legal question

Comment: In the DC Circuit's [judgment](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cadc.40415/gov.uscourts.cadc.40415.1208593674.0_3.pdf), they said that if Trump made an application to the Supreme Court for a stay of the mandate by February 12, the mandate will be withheld until the "Supreme Court’s final disposition of the application". I am not sure whether the Supreme Court is considered to have made a final disposition of the application for a stay of the mandate, since it granted certiorari instead.

Comment: @user102008: The Supreme Court would have been empowered to grant a stay if five justices wanted to grant a motion.  To grant cert, with or without staying lower proceedings, would require four, and it would not be uncommon for the Supreme Court to grant cert in a case without staying lower court proceedings even if five or more justices want to hear a case, but think the appeal would be unlikely to succeed on the merits.

Comment: @user102008: Indeed, if one circuit court decides an issue one way and is not appealed, and then one in another circuit decides the opposite way and is appealed, and all nine justices think the second circuit's ruling was correct, it would be right and proper for all nine justices to accept an appeal they knew was without merit, so as to resolve the conflict between the circuits.  Stays, however, are only to be granted when an appeal would be likely to succeed on the merits, a scenario which *the Court itself says* doesn't apply here.

Comment: @supercat: My point is that even if the Supreme Court didn't stay the mandate, the DC Circuit itself has stayed the mandate, until the "Supreme Court’s final disposition of the application". So my question is whether the Supreme Court has made a "final disposition of the application". Because if not, then the answer is simple -- the DC Circuit's stay continues by its own order.

Comment: @user102008: If the latter is the case, would there be any reason Jack Smith et al. couldn't move to lift the stay, and why the Circuit court couldn't grant the motion?